# Angular Material Design - flex wrap when going small screen

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I am trying to make the latitude and longitude to go below datakey in a column format when going smaller screen. I Played around with material design xs and  and is not working for me. Below i have the code,right now i am hiding the lat and long since they are cutting off when going to like an iPhone-5 screen size

[image]

```
div layout layout-align="space-between center">
                    <div class="md-inline-edit-input " class="dkey-inline">
                        <strong id="dkey-label">Data Key:</strong>
                        <inline-edit identifier="'asset-name'" value="$ctrl.asset" display="$ctrl.asset.dataKey" value-name="'data key'" on-update="$ctrl.updateDataKey"></inline-edit>
                    </div>


                    <div ng-if="$ctrl.asset.latitude && $ctrl.asset.longitude" class="ng-animate-disabled" layout layout-align="space-between center">
                        <div style="padding-right:15px;"><strong class="lat-long-label">{{'LABELS.LAT'|translate}}:</strong><span>{{$ctrl.asset.latitude}}</span></div>
                        <div><strong class="lat-long-label">{{'LABELS.LONG'|translate}}:</strong><span>{{$ctrl.asset.longitude}}</span></div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
       <div layout layout-xs="column" layout-align='space-between center' layout-align-xs='center start'>
                <div  class="md-inline-edit-input " class="dkey-inline">
                    <strong id="dkey-label">Data Key</strong>
                    <inline-edit identifier="'asset-name'" value="$ctrl.asset" display="$ctrl.asset.dataKey" value-name="'data key'" on-update="$ctrl.updateDataKey"></inline-edit>
                </div>
       
                <div>
                    <div  ng-if="$ctrl.asset.latitude && $ctrl.asset.longitude" class="ng-animate-disabled" layout>
                            <span layout layout-padding>
                                <strong translate="LABELS.LAT"></strong>
                                <label>{{$ctrl.asset.latitude | number: 2}}</label>
                            </span>
                            <span layout layout-padding>
                                <strong translate="LABELS.LONG"></strong>
                                <label>{{$ctrl.asset.longitude | number: 2}}</label>
                            </span>
                    </div>


                    <div ng-if="!$ctrl.asset.latitude || !$ctrl.asset.longitude" class="ng-animate-disabled">
                        <label>No Location Information Available</label>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
```

had to rewrite the whole section using material breaks.